# Nested if/then statement within foreach failing when checking if mysql row exists

Tags: php, mysql

The following code hopes to take a json feed and insert it into a mysql database as a new record OR if the record already exists, update only a few select fields within the existing record.  I cannot have the code overwrite the complete existing record, as fields within the existing record may have already been modified by users, and I cannot lose the modifications upon an udpate.

The code is executing both the IF and the ELSE for almost every record.  I assume there is something wrong with my logic or syntax on the foreach loop.   99.99% of these records are already existing.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);

// Set specified data from response
$data = $response['data'];

// Loop through the data array

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

foreach ($data as $item)
{

$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM prosp_rawdata WHERE productId = '".$item['productId']."' LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
mysql_query("UPDATE SET `affiliate_url` = '".$item['affiliate_url']."', `image_url` = '".$item['image_url']."', `price` = '".$item['price']."', `price_sale` = '".$item['price_sale']."', `percentOff` = '".$item['percentOff']."', `merchant` = '".$item['merchant']."', `dateupdate` = NOW() WHERE  `prosp_rawdata`.`productId` = '".$item['productId']."'");

echo "\n\n record exists: ";
echo $item['productId'];

}

else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO prosp_rawdata (catalogId,productId,date,affiliate_url,image_url,keyword,keywords,description,category,price,price_sale,percentOff,merchant,brand,upc) VALUES ('".$item['catalogId']."', '".$item['productId']."', NOW(), '".$item['affiliate_url']."', '".$item['image_url']."', '".$item['keyword']."', '".$item['keywords']."', '".$item['description']."', '".$item['category']."', '".$item['price']."', '".$item['price_sale']."', '".$item['percentOff']."', '".$item['merchant']."', '".$item['brand']."', '".$item['upc']."')");
}

echo "\n\n NEW RECORD: ";
echo $item['productId'];

}
}
mysql_close();
```

Output Example:

```
 NEW RECORD: a78d543c5c758ded5aea731f3ec83e79

 record exists: dae594b2082ef6002b658bbb638cc885

 NEW RECORD: dae594b2082ef6002b658bbb638cc885

 record exists: 50372f83b7a06ee2c27a2a773719d58d

 NEW RECORD: 50372f83b7a06ee2c27a2a773719d58d

 record exists: 568967b1ec527322419613d27d8e47c2

 NEW RECORD: 568967b1ec527322419613d27d8e47c2

 record exists: da2fb0cc5a0be2457c4cbb9e9d08c502

 NEW RECORD: da2fb0cc5a0be2457c4cbb9e9d08c502
```

Comment: Keep in mind that mysql_ is deprecated. Use PDO or Mysqli instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of tabulation make it hard to read. But it seems your "echoes" are outside the "else" enclosing brackets. They will be called all the time this way.

Try changing to this:

```
else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO prosp_rawdata (catalogId,productId,date,affiliate_url,image_url,keyword,keywords,description,category,price,price_sale,percentOff,merchant,brand,upc) VALUES ('".$item['catalogId']."', '".$item['productId']."', NOW(), '".$item['affiliate_url']."', '".$item['image_url']."', '".$item['keyword']."', '".$item['keywords']."', '".$item['description']."', '".$item['category']."', '".$item['price']."', '".$item['price_sale']."', '".$item['percentOff']."', '".$item['merchant']."', '".$item['brand']."', '".$item['upc']."')");
    echo "\n\n NEW RECORD: ";
    echo $item['productId'];    
}
```

Comment: Well, this is an embracing mistake.   I need to sleep.

Comment: Sleep and beer are always the best solution. :)